# Applescript dialog, Bash alias/function

Tags: applescript, bash

I'm trying to create a short alias for creating System dialogs from the Terminal. I tried to create a Bash function (since an alias didn't seem to take arguments) and add it to my .bash_profile, but it's failing me.

My latest attempt is:

```
dialog() {
    DIALOGVAR='tell app "system events" to display dialog "'$@'"'
    CMD="osascript -e 'tell app \"system events\" to activate' -e '$DIALOGVAR'"
    $CMD
}
```

But when I execute it via the Terminal, I get

```
0:1: syntax error: A unknown token can’t go here. (-2740)
```

Even though echo'ing the `CMD` variable gives me a properly formatted command:

```
osascript -e 'tell app "system events" to activate' -e 'tell app "system events" to display dialog "foo bar"'
```

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong, perhaps there's an easier way to achieve this. All I'm trying to do is to create an easy to execute command that displays dialogs.

EDIT: Alternative attempt didn't lead to anything either. This one works for arguments without spaces, but fails for multiple arguments.

```
sysdialog() {
    osascript -e "tell app \"system events\" to activate" -e "tell app \"system events\" to display dialog \"$@\""
}
```

Comment: Part of the problem is coming from storing the command in a variable before executing it; see [BashFAQ 050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: And the the problem with the second approach also has its root in the intricacies of Bash’s argument parsing: `"$@"` expands to *a list of several word arguments*, which is not what you want. Use `"$*"` instead, which expands to *a single word argument*. See the BashWiki articles [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments) and [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes). @GordonDavisson, care to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @kopischke: Actually, I don't think I have anything to add to @Lauri Ranta's answer (which I've already voted for) -- she includes the `$*` trick, and also includes a run handler trick (which makes it more robust about special characters in the message) that I didn't think of.

Comment: @GordonDavisson I agree Lauri’s answer is neat, but it does not explain *why* OP’s approaches are failing (literal vs. syntactical quoting, word splitting on parameter expansion of `"$*"` vs. `"$@"`), which you pointed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the run handler to pass arguments:

```
dialog() {
    osascript -e 'on run args
    try
    tell app "SystemUIServer" to display dialog (item 1 of args)
    end
    activate app (path to frontmost application as text)
    end' "$1"
}
```

If you want to call it like `dialog a b` (instead of `dialog 'a b'`), change `$1` to `$*`.

System Events quits automatically when it is not used, and there is a small delay when it is opened, so telling it to display the dialog would sometimes be slower.

Without the try block there would be an error if the user presses a cancel button. Without `activate` the previously focused window wouldn't get focus back when the dialog is closed.

You can use something like this to display text dialogs:

```
answer=$(osascript -e 'try
tell app "SystemUIServer"
set answer to text returned of (display dialog "" default answer "")
end
end
activate app (path to frontmost application as text)
answer' | tr '\r' ' ')
[ -z "$answer" ] && exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
#!/bin/bash
dialog() {
  DIALOGVAR=$('tell app "System Events" to display dialog "'$@'"')
  CMD=$("osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to activate'"; "osascript -e '$DIALOGVAR'")
  $CMD
  }
```